# recursively check if array contains 0 (java)

Tags: java, recursion

My method is supposed to return true if there is a at least one 0 in the array and false otherwise. However my code does not compile. why is it complaining that my method is not returning a boolean value? Can anyone help? thanks

```
  public boolean containsZero(int [] array, int i)
  {  

      if (i < array.length)
      {
          if (array[i] == 0)
             return true;
          else
           return containsZero(array, (i+1));     
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were very close, imagine what happens if your outer `if-condition` is false?

```
public boolean containsZero(int[] array, int i)
{  
  if (i < array.length)
  {
     if (array[i] == 0)
        return true;
     else
        return containsZero(array, i+1);     
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is complaining that your method does not return a boolean value because if `i >= array.length` your method does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a base case. If your i is equal to array.length you'll want to return false since you never got to a 0

```
  if (i < array.length)
  {
      if (array[i] == 0)
         return true;
      else
       return containsZero(array, (i+1));     
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
```